# Hide icons on macOS Desktop

Tags: macos, monterey

How can I not show any of the contents of the desktop folder on the desktop itself?

If I am looking at the desktop, I don't want any finder icons there. Just the desktop background picture. While still having items in the desktop folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using the macOS defaults system

1. Launch Terminal.app
2. Enter the following command line:

   `defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop false`
3. Press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to execute the command line.
4. Enter the following command line, followed by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key:

   `killall Finder`
5. This should hide the icons from the Desktop, but they will continue to show when you access the Desktop folder in Finder.
6. To display the icons back again, run the following command lines:

   `defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop true`

   followed by the command line:

   `killall Finder`